# Alphavantage It seems that the request is not executed

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, axios, fetch, fetch-api

When I execute the code fragment below, the terminal returns the console log "function called" and the "end function", but does not return the intermediate console.log(), as if the request was not being executed.
Does anyone know why?

```
export const retrieveData : Function = () => {
    console.log('function called');
    const url = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&apikey=${key}`;

    axios.get(url,{
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log('first step', response);
        // return response.json(); 
        return response; 
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log('second step');
        console.log(data)
        return 'hola'
    } )
    .then(successMessage => {
        console.log('success',successMessage);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));

    console.log('end function');

};
```

I tested the endpoint from postman with the same url and key and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

if you call `response = axios.get(url)`,
the real data is `response.data` not `response` is the parent schema. The detail information is in [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)

```
{
  // `data` is the response that was provided by the server
  data: {},

  // `status` is the HTTP status code from the server response
  status: 200,

  // `statusText` is the HTTP status message from the server response
  // As of HTTP/2 status text is blank or unsupported.
  // (HTTP/2 RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.4)
  statusText: 'OK',

  // `headers` the HTTP headers that the server responded with
  // All header names are lower cased and can be accessed using the bracket notation.
  // Example: `response.headers['content-type']`
  headers: {},

  // `config` is the config that was provided to `axios` for the request
  config: {},

  // `request` is the request that generated this response
  // It is the last ClientRequest instance in node.js (in redirects)
  // and an XMLHttpRequest instance in the browser
  request: {}
}
```

So you have to return this format

```
    axios.get(url,
        {
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
        })
    .then(response => {
        return response.data; 
    })
```

#### Demo code

save as `get-data.ts` file.

```
const axios = require('axios');

export const retrieveData: Function = () => {
    const key = 'your API key'
    console.log('function called');
    const url = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_DAILY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&apikey=${key}`;

    axios.get(url,
        {
            responseType: 'json',
            headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
        })
    .then(response => {
        return response.data; 
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4))
        return 'hola'
    })
    .then(successMessage => {
        console.log('success', successMessage);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`));
    console.log('end function');
}
retrieveData();
```

#### Transpile into JavaScript and run it

```
tsc get-data.ts
node get-data.js
```

#### Result

[image]

This is helpful to make JSON format with 4 space indent for readability.

```
JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)
```